# Angular: Replacing .toPromise() at POST-Actions

Tags: angular, rxjs

Currently, I am replacing all .toPromise()-calls in my app with the recent functions. RXJS provides two functions for it: lastValueFrom and firstValueFrom.

I already replaced all .toPromise()-calls where the data is fetched from the server or the database (GET-Method). Now I am uncertain which of the both recent functions I can use to replace toPromise() when a POST, PUT or Delete-Request is executed.

I already read the documentation and I would use for these requests the function lastValueFrom(), because I know that this observable will be executed 100%. But some resources I found say that I should use firstValueFrom().

My question is: **Which function should I use in these situations (Post-, Put-, Delete-Requests)?**

Comment: Either is fine. The observable for an http request only emits one value, so first or last makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request emits just once - it doesn't matter if you are expecting the first or the last value. There will be just one value, it will be the first and the last one. So use any function you want.

Some requests might emit multiple results (like file uploading), for them you need `lastValueFrom()`.

Comment: Okay, I see. Than you.